# how to call stored procedure in EF6 with output parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, string, stored-procedures, entity-framework-6, output-parameter

i have a stored procedure which returns a parameter containing string in it i don't know how to call it and get the output parameter to show on my view

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_test]
@room_type varchar(40)
,@room_price_min float
,@room_price_max    float
,@room_number   varchar(30)
,@new varchar(50) output
as
;
--select @room_no 
if exists(select room_number from Rooms_ms where room_number=@room_number) 
begin
    set @new='Room Already Exists'
    select @new
    return
end

insert into Rooms_ms(room_type,room_price_min,room_price_max,room_number) values
(@room_type,@room_price_min,@room_price_max,@room_number)

set @new='Successfully'
select  @new
return
```

I'm trying to catch it like below but don't know how to exactly do it.

```
 var result=   db.sp_test(a, b, 0, c);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the following to retrieve the data for a stored procedure call

```
using(var db = new iConext())
 {
   var details = db.Database.SqlQuery<iType>("exec iProc @param", new SqlParameter("@param", iValue));
 }
```

- `iType` is int or string or long or can be a ComplexType
- `@param` is one or more required parameters
- `iContext` is for your db connection

Answer (score 0):

It is one of sample my code

```
string sql = string.Format("exec sp_MyTest '" + methods.DateTimeFormat(vmodel.Search.FDate, false, 1) + "','" + methods.DateTimeFormat(vmodel.Search.TDate, false, 1) + "','" + vmodel.Search.LocationId + "',"+ 0"'");

var result = db.(DbSetName(like.Students))SqlQuery(sql).ToString();

if Return List, then 
    var result = db.(DbSetName(like.Students))SqlQuery(sql).ToList();
```